# É possível criar colunas com fórmula? Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Boa tarde. Quero saber se é possível criar uma coluna com função/fórmula (quando usamos o símbolo = )? Da mesma forma que usamos em muitas funções, tipo de =SE, =CONT.SE, =PROCV ...

Se for possível, como posso fazer isso? Porque eu tenho um planilha que em certo momento, eu quero colocar esta, suposta função/fórmula, escrevendo quantas colunas eu quero adicionar, antes de finalizar a planilha. Porque os valores que preenchem essas colunas, eles variam. Estava pensando em uma célula, se for possível. E depois de escrever o número, crie automaticamente a mesma quantidade de colunas, de acordo com o número que escrevi.

Exemplo, escrevi 2, crie duas colunas. Eu escrevi 23, crie 23 colunas ..

Comment: você provavelemnte vai ter que criar uma macro pra fazer isso.

Comment: Mas para ajudar oturas pessoas a te responderem: o que você está chamando de "criar uma coluna"? As colunas já estão todas "criadas". Quer preencher algumas células das colunas com algum valor específico? Ou só mudar a formatação?

Comment: Não, elas não estão criadas. Elas seriam geradas conforma eu especifiquei acima, digitando de alguma forma, em uma célula por exemplo a quantidade de colunas que eu quero, ai ela cria

Comment: se voce abre uma planilha nova, em branco, no excel, tem "infinitas" colunas em branco, prontas para serem preenchidas. Se você não explicar o que está chamando de "criar uma coluna" aqui, ninguém vai poder te ajudar.

Comment: Concordo com o jsbueno, a pergunta não está muito clara.